# Is it possible to disable a JavaScript file from being displayed in a php script?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a configuration in PHP so they can disable or enable a certain JavaScript (which is external) from being displayed in another PHP script, how would i do that exactly?

Like for instance

config.php

```
<?php
$javascript = enabled; /*Means js will display in html file; if it says disabled then it won't*/
?>
```

and if javascript is enabled, it will display the script:

```
<script src="bkcHANGE.js"></script>
```

Comment: I guess you'd conditionally include or not include the `<script>` element based on whatever condition you want to define.  Basically, wrap it in an `if` block just like you would any other conditionally-displayed HTML.

Comment: Can this be unclosed? i explained it in more detail

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking how to write an `if` statement.  Have you tried starting with some tutorials on PHP?  You can wrap some of your HTML in a PHP `if` statement and that HTML will only output to the page if the condition is `true`.  At the moment it really just sounds like you're looking for some PHP tutorials and examples, and the internet has many of those already.

Comment: Who is `they` in `so they can disable or enable`? What you exactly mean with `from being displayed in another PHP script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config.php

```
<?php
  $javascript_enabled = true;
?>
```

In your view

```
<?php if ($javascript_enabled): ?>
  <script src="bkcHANGE.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
<?php
if($javascript === 'enabled') {
    ?>
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

If you want to the same thing for certain scripts in an efficient way, that would be a bit more complex, here's my way to do this using OOP:

```
<?php
class Script {
    public $enabled = true;
    public $script_name;

    function __construct($enabled, $name) {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
        $this->script_name = $name . '.js';
    }
}

class ScriptControl {
    private $scripts = [];

    function __construct(array $scripts) {
        $this->scripts = $scripts;
    }

    function useScripts() {
        foreach($this->scripts as $s) {
            if($s->enabled) {
                ?>
                <script src="<?php echo $s->script_name; ?>"></script>
                <?php
            }   
        }
    }
}

//Example:
$scripts = [new Script(true, "foo"),new Script(false, "bar")];

$scriptcontrol = new ScriptControl($scripts);

$scriptcontrol->useScripts();
?>
```